# Fails to look up view in Express

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

This is the structure of my project.

app 
   -controllers 
          index.server.controller.js 
  -models 
  -routes 
        index.server.routes.js 
  -views  
        index.ejs 
config 
  -express.js

I set the view directory in my express.js file:

```
app.set('views', '../app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And this is in my controller file:

```
exports.render = function(req,res) {
res.render('index' ,  {
    title: 'welcome to this page'
})
};
```

Whenever i open localhost i get

Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "../app/views/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving it a wrong path. Try this

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../app/views');
```

Comment: It worked but i still dont understand how it was a wrong path.  Iv used the path :

require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);

in the same express.js file and it works.

Comment: __dirname will give you the path of the current file that is executing which in your case is express.js . Without setting __dirname, your computer will have no idea where to start looking for your app/views folder.

Comment: But how does it work in the case of require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app); in the same file.

I thought .. goes back one directory.

Comment: Because when you do require('../app...), you're just playing around in the file level and you can use relative paths like that. But when you do `app.set`, you can't use relative paths because now you're running a server and the server needs the location of your absolute path which is given to you by _-dirname. I know this can be a bit difficult to wrap your head around.

Comment: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` even shorter version.