# Express/Node.js Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: html, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')

app.set("view engine", 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Server Running")
    res.render('index')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I've looked over so many stackoverflow links but none of them seem to work. Here are some of the links I've looked over:

[Error: Failed to lookup view in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216395/error-failed-to-lookup-view-in-express)
[Fails to look up view in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026117/fails-to-look-up-view-in-expresss)
[Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480227/failed-to-lookup-view-error-in-views-directory)
[Express app: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386166/express-app-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory-views)
[Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608841/failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory)
[Error: Failed to lookup view in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216395/error-failed-to-lookup-view-in-express)

I can't seem to tell if I am missing something that's in those links. My views folder is named 'views' no extra whitespace. My file organization is as follows.
server.js
views
--index.html